# Recover data from an expired iOS developer installed app?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have an old build of an iOS app under development on my iPhone.  The app no longer runs (says "No Longer Available" when tapped), and Xcode says it is "Unable to install" an updated build of the app onto my iPhone, both likely because the old build of my app was installed a few months ago using an old developer profile which has expired. Both the old and new builds belong to the same Developer account and have identical App IDs.  Xcode seems to have created some updated provisioning profiles when I renewed my enrollment in the Apple Developer program several months ago.

I could delete the old build from my iPhone, which would allow me to install the newer build, but then I would lose any data created or saved by the use of the old build.

Is there any way to recover the data from the old expired build of my app on my iPhone?

Comment: What does "recover the data" mean? What "data" does a _build_ have?

Comment: Data that the user of the app creates or downloads into the app's private container.

Comment: Do you care about all users or are you just talking about you? If the latter, the data is your backups.  Maybe Xcode can even see and fetch it in the Devices window.

Comment: If you can verify that either of those methods actually work, you can make that an answer.

Comment: That is for _you_ to verify.

Comment: Applies to any app installed via Xcode (on corporate test devices, etc.)